# Trying to remove extra spaces from clipboard using bash from applescript

Tags: bash, applescript

I am trying to remove all the formating from the data in the clipboard.

The input is like this:

```
Name:   William R Wells
Date of Birth:  8 Dec 1942
Birth Place:    Fayette, Kentucky, USA
Mother's name:  Suda Hatton
Volume Number:  179
Certificate Number: 89145
Volume Year:    1942
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Name: William R Wells, Date of Birth: 8 Dec 1942, Birth Place: Fayette, Kentucky, USA, Mother's name: Suda Hatton, Volume Number: 179, Certificate, Number: 89145, Volume Year: 1942
```

This script works but does not delete the extra spaces and place a comma after the data.

```
try 
    do shell script "export LC_CTYPE=UTF-8; pbpaste | fmt -w 99999 | pbcopy"        
end try
end
```

Any suggestions? 
Thanks
Roger

Comment: Replacing `fmt` with `perl -0p -e 's/$(?!\Z)/, /gm; s/\s+/ /g'` might do what you want.

Comment: After more head banging and a nap here is what I want to do. Get the string from the clipboard, find and replace all hex 09 or tab with a hex 20 space, find and replace all hex 0A or line feed with a hex 2C20 or comma space. then write it back to the clipboard.

Comment: Did the perl I gave above not work? If so, could you provide a [mcve] so I can **see** it not work with my own eyes? Looks perfect at https://ideone.com/F6dDzr, f/e.

Comment: ...by contrast, if the perl is fine on its own but there's a problem with `pbpaste | ... | pbcopy` as a workflow, that's a separate issue (and a very believable one -- keep in mind that all pieces of a pipeline are started simultaneously, so whether the code is safe may depend on implementation details such as whether `pbcopy` waits for an EOF on stdin before it interacts with the clipboard at all, and whether your platform's clipboard is implemented with an atomic-transaction model).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an AppleScript that will do the job.  Not sure it's the most efficient way, but it works.

```
    use framework "Foundation"
    use scripting additions
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    get the clipboard as text

    re_match from the result against "\t+" given replacement:" "
    re_match from the result against "[\r\n]" given replacement:", "
    re_match from the result against " +" given replacement:" "

    set the clipboard to the result
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ###HANDLERS
    on re_match against pattern from str given replacement:fmt
        set regex to current application's NSRegularExpression's ¬
            regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern ¬
                options:(current application's ¬
                NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive) ¬
                |error|:(missing value)

        (regex's stringByReplacingMatchesInString:str ¬
            options:0 range:{0, length of str} ¬
            withTemplate:fmt) ¬
            as text
    end re_match
```

This next AppleScript is much simpler and shorter but less versatile.  However, if your clipboard contents is largely the same in format, it should be as effective as the above script.

```
    set str to the clipboard as text

    set text item delimiters to {null, tab}
    set str to text items of str as text
    set the text item delimiters to {", ", linefeed, return}
    set str to text items of str as text
    set the text item delimiters to {": ", ":"}
    set str to text items of str as text

    set the clipboard to str
```

Comment: CJK Work perfect Thanks

Comment: @user2751396 [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)